# Построение простейшего синтаксического анализатора выражений

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте!
Появилась задача "Построение простейшего синтаксического анализатора выражений". Это лаб. работа... Прежде никогда с таким не сталкивался... Основная проблема - не удобно извлечь цифры из строки и выполнить последовательно операции. Есть какая-то библиотека, которая достает отсюда только числа vector<string> gh;?
Спасибо.

Comment: @Alerr, обычно синтаксический анализатор использует лексический анализатор для получения лексем.

Вот в качестве первого шага его и надо написать. А  потом вызывать, например:

    lexem_t lx;
    ....
    while (lx = get_lexem(input)) {
       switch (lexem_type(lx)) {
           ...


Это, если делать все руками. А по настоящему, часто для генерации лексического анализатора используют, например Flex, а синтаксичского - Bison.

Comment: Вот бы кто статью об этом толковую написал, было бы круто.

Comment: @SoloMio, статью о чем? Как Flex с Bison-ом использовать?

Comment: >Вот бы кто статью об этом толковую написал, было бы круто

я вас удивлю, но на тему синтаксического разбора уже написаны десятки книг, сотни или тысячи статей, множество научных работ, и все это давным-давно проходят в институтах будущие программисты

Comment: @DreamChild, ну, а мы не проходили.

Comment: меня всегда удивляют студенты, которые получают задание и утверждают, что они это не проходили. Либо они действительно не проходили (то есть, прогуливали), либо просто не поняли, что проходили.

Comment: @SoloMio либо вас хреново учили, либо вы сами учились соответствующим образом. Теория компиляторов, синтаксический разбор, самостоятельное написание компилятора - это то, что любой уважающий себя программист обязан хотя бы попробовать на вкус. Так или иначе, чему бы вас ни учили в институте, это хорошо известная, многократно описанная и изученная тема, поэтому если вам это действительно интересно, то проблемы в поиске теоретических материалов нет вовсе - как я уже говорил, есть ряд очень хороших книг

Comment: Вот интересно, вопрос задал @Alerr, а пинают @SoloMio.

--

Кстати, я вот, толковых и не занудных статей на эту тему на русском тоже не знаю. 

На самом деле материала много, но краткого и толкового изложения не видел (вспоминается что-то в какой-то старой книжке (IMHO издательства Мир, м.б. и перевод Вирта) о Pascal с примером рекурсивного разбора калькулятора, но точно уже не помню).

Comment: есть, есть. Рекомендую поискать в гугле "давайте напишем компилятор Креншоу". Да, там примеры на паскале (хотя в середине уже и на с попадаются). Но после прочтения написать свой парсер выражений (не обязательно арифметических) будет очень просто.

Comment: @avp возможно, аналога "Занимательной физики" от Я.И. Перельмана по теории компиляторов и нет, однако все же утверждение "вот бы кто статью об этом толковую написал" звучит несколько странно. Учитывая, что такому труду, как "Книга дракона" уже лет 30, не меньше. Вот даже у Страуструпа, как говорилось ниже, есть глава, в которой рассказывается о лексемах и грамматиках

Comment: Пришлось удалять и вставлять коммент. Лимит-с.

--

@KoVadim, это хорошо, что они есть.

Хотя я в этом плане не о себе беспокоюсь...

--

@DreamChild, я понимаю, что тема не простая. Вот глянул на этого Креншоу. 750K HTML весит.  Если автор в том же духе продолжит делать обещанные в конце функции, массивы и собственные типы данных, то вырастет до 2M.

А все что там сходу просматривается можно уложить страниц в 30.

Но вот будут-ли они понятны и интересны? 

--

А SoloMio IMHO спрашивал о Flex с Bison. Наверняка перевод O'Reilly где-то есть, но ведь объем...

--

Все, место кончилось.

Comment: @avp для написания комментариев побольше есть маленький грязный хак - написать его как ответ, а потом преобразовать в комментарий)

Comment: @DreamChild, мы действительно этого не проходили. Тема интересна, но сколько я не пробовал читать статьи о том что такое контекстно-свободная грамматика и БНФ так нихрена и не понял, если честно. Конечно, это не значит что я забью и вобще перестану копать эту тему, но, в действительности, далеко не после каждой статьи возникает четкое понимание предмета. Помнится даже читал какое-то "мягкое введение" во Flex, но это мне тоже не помогло. А книга дракона (Dragon book) мне показалась невероятно скучной.

Comment: @DreamChild, моя специальность называлась компьютерные сети и системы, а не "Программирование". И пары я не прогуливал. Так что не надо тут.

Comment: >> меня всегда удивляют студенты, которые получают задание и утверждают, что они это не проходили. 

Могли и не проходить, я на всю жизнь запомнил самый первый семинар по вышке - лектор поменял местами темы и начал с плоскостей, на что семинаристка сказала что это проблемы лектора и что мы не проходили определители ее не волнует, вперед решать задачу

Comment: Всё!!!, Спасибо всем большое!) Все получилось как нельзя лучше) Все работает)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можешь найти что-то интересное, даже нужное, в книге Бьярне Страуструпа "Программирование. Принципы и практика использования C++. - 2011". Там во главе "Создание программ" разрабатывается калькулятор, который вычисляет выражения. Там всё по шагам, и очень понятно. Приводится код.) Надеюсь поможет! Есть в электронном виде.